# Nested Subseting

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame

```
Library(dplyr)    
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Tag <- c(1,2,6,1,3,4,6,4,3)
Value <- c(5,9,3,3,5,6,4,8,9)
DF <- data.frame(ID,Tag,Value)

  ID Tag Value
1  1   1     5
2  1   2     9
3  1   6     3
4  2   1     3
5  2   3     5
6  2   4     6
7  2   6     4
8  3   4     8
9  3   3     9
```

I would like to perform the following 1) group by rows ID 2) assign the Value corresponding to a specific Tag a new column. In the following example, I am assigning the Value of Tag 6 to a new column by ID

```
  ID Tag Value New_Value 
1  1   1     5         3
2  1   2     9         3
3  1   6     3         3
4  2   1     3         4
5  2   3     5         4
6  2   4     6         4
7  2   6     4         4
8  3   4     8         NA
9  3   3     9         NA
```

To the best of my knowledge, I need to subset the data in each group to get the Value for Tag 6. Here is my code and the error msg

```
DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(New_Value = select(filter(.,Tag==6),Value))
Adding missing grouping variables: `ID`
Error: Column `New_Value` is of unsupported class data.frame
```

Another possible solution is to create a new dataframe with IDs and Values for Tag 6 and join it with DF. However, I believe there is a better generic solution by only using dplyr.

I would appreciate it if you can help me understand how to perform a nested subset in this situation

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that `Tag` is unique within groups, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(New_Value = ifelse(any(Tag == 6), Value[Tag == 6], NA))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID   Tag Value New_Value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     1     5         3
2     1     2     9         3
3     1     6     3         3
4     2     1     3         4
5     2     3     5         4
6     2     4     6         4
7     2     6     4         4
8     3     4     8        NA
9     3     3     9        NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain "Value[Tag == 6]". Is Value acting as a dataframe? Is this a special feature of dplyr?

Comment: No to both questions.  It is subsetting `Value` when `Tag` equals 6 which is why I commented that this approach will only work if `Tag` is unique within groups.  Perhaps take a look at `help("[")`